# Editing PDF file contents in a batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, pdf

I have a small working batch script that creates pdf files from adoc files and then merge those pdf files into one.

Is it possible to edit the contents of that merged pdf file using the batch script itself? Are there any windows commands or any other command line tools?

Thanks!